# AndroidX DataStore - AES/CBC/PKCS7 - javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException

Tags: android, protocol-buffers, android-keystore, android-jetpack-datastore

I read Mark Allison's [blog post](https://blog.stylingandroid.com/datastore-security/?unapproved=114499&moderation-hash=f2a7fe6f56bdcfe6ca8ee02eac91a508#comment-114499) about combining the new [Android DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore) with encryption with the use of the Android Keystore.

I'm using the same exact SecretKey properties (AES/CBC/PKCS7) and Encrypt/Decrypt found in his blog.

```kotlin
class AesCipherProvider(
    private val keyName: String,
    private val keyStore: KeyStore,
    private val keyStoreName: String
) : CipherProvider {

    override val encryptCipher: Cipher
        get() = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION).apply {
            init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getOrCreateKey())
        }

    override fun decryptCipher(iv: ByteArray): Cipher =
        Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION).apply {
            init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getOrCreateKey(), IvParameterSpec(iv))
        }

    private fun getOrCreateKey(): SecretKey =
        (keyStore.getEntry(keyName, null) as? KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry)?.secretKey
            ?: generateKey()

    private fun generateKey(): SecretKey =
        KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM, keyStoreName)
            .apply { init(keyGenParams) }
            .generateKey()

    private val keyGenParams =
        KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
            keyName,
            KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
        ).apply {
            setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE)
            setEncryptionPaddings(PADDING)
            setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
            setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(true)
        }.build()

    private companion object {
        const val ALGORITHM = KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES
        const val BLOCK_MODE = KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC
        const val PADDING = KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_PKCS7
        const val TRANSFORMATION = "$ALGORITHM/$BLOCK_MODE/$PADDING"
    }
}
```

```kotlin
class CryptoImpl constructor(private val cipherProvider: CipherProvider) : Crypto {

    override fun encrypt(rawBytes: ByteArray, outputStream: OutputStream) {
        val cipher = cipherProvider.encryptCipher
        val encryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(rawBytes)
        with(outputStream) {
            write(cipher.iv.size)
            write(cipher.iv)
            write(encryptedBytes.size)
            write(encryptedBytes)
        }
    }

    override fun decrypt(inputStream: InputStream): ByteArray {
        val ivSize = inputStream.read()
        val iv = ByteArray(ivSize)
        inputStream.read(iv)
        val encryptedDataSize = inputStream.read()
        val encryptedData = ByteArray(encryptedDataSize)
        inputStream.read(encryptedData)
        val cipher = cipherProvider.decryptCipher(iv)
        return cipher.doFinal(encryptedData)
    }
}
```

I'm using following super simple ProtocolBuffer with only one `String` field.

```
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "my.package.model";

message SimpleData {
    string text = 1;
}
```

I'm using following code to test this implementation.

```kotlin
class SecureSimpleDataSerializer(private val crypto: Crypto) :
    Serializer<SimpleData> {

    override fun readFrom(input: InputStream): SimpleData {
        return if (input.available() != 0) {
            try {
                SimpleData.ADAPTER.decode(crypto.decrypt(input))
            } catch (exception: IOException) {
                throw CorruptionException("Cannot read proto", exception)
            }
        } else {
            SimpleData("")
        }
    }

    override fun writeTo(t: SimpleData, output: OutputStream) {
        crypto.encrypt(SimpleData.ADAPTER.encode(t), output)
    }

    override val defaultValue: SimpleData = SimpleData()
}

private val simpleDataStore = createDataStore(
    fileName = "SimpleDataStoreTest.pb",
    serializer = SecureSimpleDataSerializer(
        CryptoImpl(
            AesCipherProvider(
                "SimpleDataKey",
                KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore").apply { load(null) },
                "AndroidKeyStore"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

When I try to serialize and deserialize a simple `String` it works like intended.

```kotlin
simpleDataStore.updateData { it.copy(text = "simple-string") }
println(simpleDataStore.data.first())
// "simple-string"
```

However when I try the same with a longer `String` (note smaller than the max size for Proto's).
The save works, but upon killing the app and relaunching the app to retrieve the value it crashes.

```kotlin
simpleDataStore.updateData { it.copy(text = "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") }
println(simpleDataStore.data.first())
```

```
Process: com.stylingandroid.datastore, PID: 13706
    javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:513)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055)
        at com.stylingandroid.datastore.security.CryptoImpl.decrypt(Crypto.kt:33)
        at com.stylingandroid.datastore.ui.MainActivity$SecureSimpleDataSerializer.readFrom(MainActivity.kt:32)
        at com.stylingandroid.datastore.ui.MainActivity$SecureSimpleDataSerializer.readFrom(MainActivity.kt:26)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readData(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:249)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readDataOrHandleCorruption(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:227)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readAndInitOnce(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:190)
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$actor$1.invokeSuspend(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:154)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
     Caused by: android.security.KeyStoreException: Invalid input length
        at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:1301)
        at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.doFinal(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:176)
        at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:506)
        at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2055) 
        at com.stylingandroid.datastore.security.CryptoImpl.decrypt(Crypto.kt:33) 
        at com.stylingandroid.datastore.ui.MainActivity$SecureSimpleDataSerializer.readFrom(MainActivity.kt:32) 
        at com.stylingandroid.datastore.ui.MainActivity$SecureSimpleDataSerializer.readFrom(MainActivity.kt:26) 
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readData(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:249) 
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readDataOrHandleCorruption(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:227) 
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore.readAndInitOnce(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:190) 
        at androidx.datastore.core.SingleProcessDataStore$actor$1.invokeSuspend(SingleProcessDataStore.kt:154) 
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:738) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678) 
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665) 
2021-01-10 14:08:09.907 13706-13706/com.stylingandroid.datastore I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13706 SIG: 9
```

Does anybody know?
Is it specific to the String's length in combination with the chosen encryption algorithm?
Is the decryption function wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is reproducible on my machine. It occurs when the encrypted data `encryptedBytes` in `CryptoImpl.encrypt` has a length of more than 255 bytes. The reason is that starting with 256 bytes `encryptedBytes.size` cannot be stored on one byte, while the methods `int InputStream.read()` or `void OutputStream.write(int)` read or write only one byte.

Therefore, if the size of the ciphertext is to be written, a sufficiently large bytes buffer must be used in `CryptoImpl.encrypt`, e.g. 4 bytes:

```kotlin
with(outputStream) {
    write(cipher.iv.size)
    write(cipher.iv)
    write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(encryptedBytes.size).array())   // Convert Int to 4 bytes buffer
    write(encryptedBytes)
}
```

and for reading in `CryptoImpl.decrypt`:

```kotlin
val ivSize = inputStream.read()
val iv = ByteArray(ivSize)
inputStream.read(iv)

val encryptedDataSizeBytes = ByteArray(4)
inputStream.read(encryptedDataSizeBytes)
val encryptedDataSize = ByteBuffer.wrap(encryptedDataSizeBytes).int     // Convert 4 bytes buffer to Int
val encryptedData = ByteArray(encryptedDataSize)
inputStream.read(encryptedData)
```

---

However, writing the sizes is actually not necessary. The size of the IV is known, it corresponds to the block size, i.e. 16 bytes for AES, so that the criterion for the separation of IV and ciphertext is defined. Thus, the data can be written in `CryptoImpl.encrypt` as follows:

```kotlin
with(outputStream) {
    write(cipher.iv)                         // Write 16 bytes IV 
    write(encryptedBytes)                    // Write ciphertext
}
```

And for reading in `CryptoImpl.decrypt`:

```kotlin
val iv = ByteArray(16)
inputStream.read(iv)                         // Read IV (first 16 bytes) 
val encryptedData = inputStream.readBytes()  // Read ciphertext (remaining data)
```

Comment: Thank you.
Any way to let the CryptoImpl not 'hardcode'  the IV size and make this class more re-usable?

Comment: oh I see it's the first solution :)

Comment: Both solutions do not change the IV generation, i.e. as before a _random_ IV is _implicitly_ generated when initializing the `Cipher` instance in `AesCipherProvider.encryptCipher`.